# Pass value from activity to Fragment getItem(int position)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-toolbar, android-tablayout

I'm sorry if this question is inappropriate but I need some help. I have a 3-tabs app, which will view the first tab when open the app.

Objective: After registration, users will view their profile, which in third tab.

What I have done: in `RegisterActivity`, I set a value in bundle, which will pass to `MainActivity`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("profile", 2);
intent.putExtra("from", "register");
```

So in `MainActivity`,

```
profile = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("profile");
from = getIntent().getExtras().getString("from");

final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(profile);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
```

I managed to get the value from `RegisterActivity`, but I don't know where should I place the `int profile` value. I want the value get passed to `getItem` method in `PagerAdapter`.

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
int mNumOfTabs;

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            SearchGroupsFragment searchGroupsFragment = new SearchGroupsFragment();
            return searchGroupsFragment;
        case 1:
            RegisterGroupFragment registerGroupFragment = new RegisterGroupFragment();
            return registerGroupFragment;
        case 2:
            ProfileFragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
            return profileFragment;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
}
```

}

So that when the users successfully register, they will directly view the third tab. Or is there any other way to view it?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

I followed the answers below and managed to get what I want - after `RegisterActivity`, the view I get is third tab with its layout. But when I moved to second or first tab, the layout doesn't change. There's no animation or movement of tab changing. Simply put, the layout of third tab got 'stuck' and didn't change for 2nd and 1st tab.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you move this portion of your code to your **MainActivity** `OnCreate`

```
final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
```

Start your **RegisterActivity** like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1001);
```

In **RegisterActivity**, return the result back to **MainActivity** like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("profile", 2);
intent.putExtra("from", "register");
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

And in **MainActivity**, override `onActivityResult`

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == 1001 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        int profile = data.getExtras().getInt("profile");
        String from = data.getExtras().getString("from");
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(profile)
    }
}
```

Comment: means, leave `onTabSelected` empty?

Comment: Yes. _Updated answer_

Comment: all 3 tabs have same fragment layout now

Comment: Are you starting RegisterActivity from the MainActivity?

Comment: from a fragment (the same profile tab) in MainActivity

Comment: Since you're starting `RegisterActivity` from `MainActivity`, you might want to use `startActivityForResult` instead. **Updated answer with startActivityForResult`

Answer (score 0):

You can move the viewpager to specific page with

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(index or position of page);
```

Note: call this method after viewPager.setApapter();

Blessings.

Comment: weird.. now all 3 tabs have same fragment and the selected tab is the first one, not third

Comment: i removed `viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener` and `tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener`

Comment: If you want listen when the view pager change you should use

Comment: otherwise when you want move the view pager to specific page, you call this method and pass the position of the page, in this case the profile fragment called when the view pager is on position 2. So you need to call viewPager.setCurrentItem(2); for move viewpager to profile fragment. The Listener for viewpager is only use when you want make some changes to especific page.